# multiple test listeners in Katalon Studio

Tags: java, katalon-studio

## What we're starting with

I have a main test listener, which just set up the web driver on set up, and free the resource on teardown:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.AfterTestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.BeforeTestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.context.TestCaseContext
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory

import internal.GlobalVariable



class NewTestListener {
    private WebDriver driver;

    /**
     * Executes before every test case starts.
     * @param testCaseContext related information of the executed test case.
     */
    @BeforeTestCase
    def sampleBeforeTestCase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
        String pathToChromeDriver = System.getProperty("user.home") + GlobalVariable.pathToKatalon + '\\configuration\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'

        System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', pathToChromeDriver)

        ChromeOptions chromeProfile = new ChromeOptions()

        chromeProfile.addArguments('user-data-dir=' + System.getProperty("user.home") + GlobalVariable.pathToUserDataDir)

        chromeProfile.addArguments('profile-directory=Default')

        this.driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeProfile)

        this.driver.manage().window().maximize()

        this.driver.get('https://crm.zoho.com')

        DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(this.driver)
    }

    @AfterTestCase
    def sampleAfterTestCase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
        this.driver.quit()
    }
}
```

## What we're tryna do

I have dozens of test cases, that pertain to distinct pages, categorized under distinct folders, which I want to abstract out common set up,teardown concerns.

### How do we want to do it

I try to create some `BaseCategoryListener`, which get implemented by the category of test:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.AfterTestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.BeforeTestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.context.TestCaseContext

abstract class BaseCategoryListener {

    abstract List<Pattern> getCategory();

    public void setup(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
    }

    public void teardown(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
    }

    boolean isInCategory(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
        for (Pattern regex : this.getCategory()) {
            if (regex.matcher(testCaseContext.getTestCaseId()).matches()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Executes before every test case starts.
     * @param testCaseContext related information of the executed test case.
     */
    @BeforeTestCase
    def sampleBeforeTestCase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
        if (this.isInCategory(testCaseContext)) {
            this.setup(testCaseContext)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes after every test case ends.
     * @param testCaseContext related information of the executed test case.
     */
    @AfterTestCase
    def sampleAfterTestCase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
        if (this.isInCategory(testCaseContext)) {
            this.teardown(testCaseContext)
        }
    }
}
```

implement it like so:

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import java.util.regex.Pattern

import com.kms.katalon.core.context.TestCaseContext
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

class ContractTestsListener extends BaseCategoryListener{

    @Override
    public List<Pattern> getCategory() {
        return [
            ~/Test Cases\/New Zoho\/Practice Contract\/.*/
        ]
    }

    @Override
    public void setup(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
        WebUI.navigateToUrl(testCaseContext.getTestCaseVariables()["initURL"])

        WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Practice - Zoho CRM/Third Row Section/Contract Tab Pane/New Contract button'))

        WebUI.waitForElementNotPresent(findTestObject('Page_Practice - Zoho CRM/Third Row Section/Contract Tab Pane/New Contract button'), 3)

        WebUI.waitForPageLoad(5)
    }
}
```

## What happens when you try to use that:

When I pick a test case in the folder `Test Cases/New Zoho/Practice Contract` to remove the setup hook from (because it was already copied and pasted into the test listener), that test case now fails *because the `ContractTestsListener` setup happens before the `NewTestListener` setup*!

How can I control the flow of the test listener hooks in Katalon Studio?

Comment: Where are you using NewTestListener? Have you extended it in any of these classes? How do you know NewTestListener is even executing?

Comment: It is a registered test listener, auto-generated by Katalon Studio and filled in by me. 

No, I haven't extended it. Is that the answer here: extend it and its setup and teardown methods?

Comment: As for how we know it is executing, the browser sets up and tears down, per its set up and teardown code, on every test case, without having to tightly couple that code into the test case itself.